# Некорректная работа функции strcmp

Tags: c, массивы, строки

Здравствуйте. У меня некорректно работает функция strcmp.
Код:

```
int Part1(int* GlobalDigit, int Count, int* sptr) {
    char LocalChar[30]; char Temp[2]; char TempLocalChar[8]; 
    char* enqueue = "enqueue"; char *dequeque = "dequeque"; char *done = "done";
    //TempLocalChar[7] = '/0';
    int LocalDigit;
    int LocalCount;
    int FuncAnsw; int Check = 0;
        rewind(stdin);
        gets(LocalChar);
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
            TempLocalChar[i] = LocalChar[i];
        }

        if (strcmp(TempLocalChar, done) == 1) {
        //Бла-бла-бла
        }
        if (strcmp(TempLocalChar, enqueue) == 1 ) {
            //Бла-бла-бла
        }
        if (strcmp(TempLocalChar, dequeque) == 1) {
     //Бла-бла-бла
        }
        if (Check == 0) {
       //Бла-бла-бла
        }
    }
```

При вводе "enqueue 7" `strcmp(TempLocalChar, enqueue)` возвращает 1. (остальные - 0)

При вводе "dequeque" `strcmp(TempLocalChar, dequeque)` возвращает 1. (остальные - 0)

При вводе "done" `strcmp(TempLocalChar, done)` возвращает НОЛЬ.(
`strcmp(TempLocalChar, enqueue)` возвращает 0.
`strcmp(TempLocalChar, dequeque)` возвращает ОДИН.)

Не подскажите, как пофиксить?

Comment: Пофиксить очень просто: нужно посмотреть что на самом деле находится в переменной `TempLocalChar` на момент вызова `strcmp()`. И, судя по коду, явно не то, что представляется. Кстати, значение `1` говорит о том, что строки *не равны*, а `0` - *равны*.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При вводе строки "enqueue 7" в символьный массив, добавляется также завершающий ноль.

В этом цмкле

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        TempLocalChar[i] = LocalChar[i];
    }
```

копируется подстрока `"enqueue"` без азвершающего нуля. Поэтому данные if предложения с вызовом `strcmp`

```
    if (strcmp(TempLocalChar, enqueue) == 1 ) {
        //Бла-бла-бла
    }
```

имеют неопределенное поведение, так как функция `strcmp` сравнивает лишь строки с завершающем нулем (кстати сказать, это и есть определение строки, то есть должен присутствовать завершающий ноль)

Вам следует после копирования подстроки добавит завершающий ноль. Например,

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        TempLocalChar[i] = LocalChar[i];
    }

    TempLocalChar[7] = '\0';
```

Или вы могли бы сравнивать строки, используя другую стандартную функцию, а именно, `memcmp`, которая позволяет явно задать, сколько символов сравнивается.

Например,

```
    if ( memcmp( TempLocalChar, enqueue, 7 ) == 0 ) {
        //Бла-бла-бла
    }
```

Кстати сказать, если вы хотите проверить строки на равенство, то надо писать

```
    if (strcmp(TempLocalChar, enqueue) == 0 ) {
                                        ^^^^
        //Бла-бла-бла
    }
```

Имейте в виду, что стандарт C, не гарантирует, что в случае, если строки не равны, то будет возвращено именно 1 или -1. Функция может вернуть любое положительное или отрицательное значение. Поэтоу такое сравнение

```
    if (strcmp(TempLocalChar, enqueue) == 1 ) {
        //Бла-бла-бла
    }
```

в любом случае не корректно. Правильно було бы написать, например

```
    if (strcmp(TempLocalChar, enqueue) > 0 ) {
        //Бла-бла-бла
    }
```

или

```
    if (strcmp(TempLocalChar, enqueue) < 0 ) {
        //Бла-бла-бла
    }
```

Гарантируется только возвращение 0 в случае равенства строк.

Вообще говоря, использование таких магических чисел, как 7, используемая в цикле, делает программы подверженными ошибкам, так как неизвестно, что на самом деле ввел пользователь в символьный массив, действительно ли более 7 знаков или меньше.

Также обратите внимание на то, что функция `gets` не надежная и больше не поддерживается стандартом языка C. Вместо нее используйте стандартную функцию `fgets`, которая позволяет сообщить, сколько можно вводить в массив символов.

Вы можете написать

```
fgets( LocalChar, sizeof( localChar ), stdin );
```

Эта функция добавляет массив также символ новый строки. Удалить его из массива можно следующим образом

```
localChar[ strcspn( localChar, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
gets(LocalChar);
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
    TempLocalChar[i] = LocalChar[i];
}
```

Посмотрим, что будет в строке `TempLocalChar` при вводе `"enqueue 7"`:

```
"enqueueКАКОЙ-ТО-МУСОР"
```

Стало быть, `strcmp(TempLocalChar, "enqueue")` вернёт `1` (а может и `-1`), что корректно.

Ввод `"dequeque"`:

```
"dequequКАКОЙ-ТО-МУСОР"
```

Значит, `strcmp(TempLocalChar, "dequeque")` вернёт `1` (а может и `-1`), что тоже корректно.

Ввод `"done"`:

```
"done\0КАКОЙ-ТО-МУСОР"
```

И `strcmp(TempLocalChar, "done")` вернёт `0`, это тоже корректно.

Таким образом, некорректна не работа `strcmp()`, а вот это уверждение:

> Некорректная работа функции strcmp